# Track Mobile Network Settings checkbox

Tags: android, mobile, settings

[image]

- I am working on one network app, i have problem with tracking those red
  marks check box. means that if "Data Enable" is check than
  pro-grammatically i know in my App this Data Enable is check or
  UN-check.
- so like that all Data roaming and Use only 2G networks Also track.
- i was lots of try to maintain track this but i can't success, i
  really want help.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways for this...

You have ConnectivityManager class in android. Did you try using that?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

This is available to let you know about the network state of your device.

**What you can do?**

1. And you can receive automatic notification of when the connection state changes via the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcast
2. You can setup your Broadcast receiver and register your application to broadcast an Action
3. Alernatively you can also work with services depends upto Architecture of your application

I guess any internet connection should be fine for you if you only worried about Internet

Then start your process as you want to. :)

Comment: when the connection state changes via the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcast. But I track as a hardware button, not network status. you got my point...?

Comment: hardware button?? am not sure if i am understanding it correctly!

Comment: Ok, i describe here. if in my android phone have  no sim card available and i have to manual change data enable check box is Enabled. then how can i know that using application this Data Enabled Button  is Enabled  or Disable.